# Mongodb Nodejs Regex Query

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, mongodb

I am using the module "mongodb" to query mongodb from node js APIs. I am trying to search contacts document by a search query. The selector for the same is as below:

```
selector['users.name'] = {$regex: new RegExp(params.query), $options:"i"}
```

Consider the name of the user is "Sagar Gopale" and the search query is "sagar" or even "gopale" then the above works fine and returns results properly. But if I input search query as "sagar gopale" it returns empty result. Can someone provide me a solution so that I can input the search query including the space?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the space between `sagar` and `gopale` is a regular `\x20` space?

Answer (score 2):

Actualy you will have many difficulties here if you stick with the `regexp` aproach, I suggest you to create a `text` index:

```
collection.createIndex({"users.name" : "text"});
```

And then when you will search:

```
db.collection('users').find({
  $text: {
    $search: params.query,
    $caseSensitive: false,
  }
});
```

In this way you will get the result when you use "Sagar", "sagar", "sagar gopa", "gopale sagar", and many combinations of those 2.

This aproach works very nicely if you have an autocomplete, or the client doesn't know exactly the name. Mongo dispose of strong text search algorithms that will match letters, even if they are not in proper order.